# Programmatically add Button to MapFragment / GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

is there any way to programmatically add a Button to a MapFragment or directly onto a GoogleMap object without using XML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is, well not directly to the map fragment, but you can place any layout you want above it (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`...) in your layout file and then add a view to this layout programmaticly as you would with another, using this method:

```
layout.addView(YourButtonYouWantToAdd);
```

That way your button will appear on top of your map fragment.